# Axios not returning value

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-web-api, axios

I am calling an API method in axios like:

```
  let promise = axios.get('http://localhost:63711/api/AdminAPI/GetHomeCarousel');
  console.log(promise);
  promise.then(function(response){
    console.log(response);
  });
```

Both console.log print the output:

`Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending", [[PromiseValue]]: undefined}`

The api is `GET` and is returning valid json data, I have checked via POSTMAN like:

```
[
    {
        "type": "image",
        "mediaUrls": [
            "\\wwwroot\\11863226_431355017048701_7276274176291220216_n.jpg"
        ],
        "title": "title 1",
        "description": "<p>Check pic&nbsp;</p>\r\n<p>test yy jjasd</p>",
        "url": "\\NdbSite\\wwwroot\\11863226_431355017048701_7276274176291220216_n.jpg",
        "buttonText": "",
        "featuredProduct": "",
        "featuredProductUrl": ""
    }
]
```

I followed :

http://codeheaven.io/how-to-use-axios-as-your-http-client/

what I am missing?

Comment: I'm fairly certain that the `console.log` output for `console.log(response)` could never be a pending Promise object.  I'd check that again.

Comment: Does `axios.get('http://localhost:63711/api/AdminAPI/GetHomeCarousel').then(function(response) { console.log(response) });` give you the same result?

Comment: Not really sure why your code isn't working, I tested it here: http://jsbin.com/wohobaboje/edit?html,js,output and it appears to be fine.  I would double check that your API is working properly.

Comment: can you change the url and try to 'http://localhost:63711/api/AdminAPI/GetHomeCarousel/' , put '/' in the end and try once?

Comment: same problem.. any updates on this? relevant xkcd: https://xkcd.com/979/

Answer (score 2):

I discovered that this behavior does occur when you make an axios request within a function preceded by `async` but you neglect to prepend the `await` keyword to the request call.

Obviously this is not the solution for the OP, but it may help some others who land here.

In the code below, it would happen if you removed the `await` keyword.

```
async get(axios, resourceUrl) {
    const response = await axios.$get(resourceUrl);
    return { response };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing that you need to resolve the promise. Not sure why you are doing in this way, you can perfectly try this:

```
axios
  .get('http://localhost:63711/api/AdminAPI/GetHomeCarousel')
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I solved with switching place `catch` and `then`. `catch` going first.

I use `axios 0.17.1`